# How to use ENV vars in golang to pass DB connection values dynamically when deployed in kubernetes

Tags: database, postgresql, go, kubernetes

I am currently developing a small API in golang which will connect to a sql database. Below is the snip where I am passing the database connection string details statically ( hardcoded in the code ) .

```
const (
DB_USER     = "username"
DB_PASSWORD = "password"
DB_NAME     = "db_name"
DB_HOST     = "db_server_name"
DB_PORT     = db_port )
```

Now I want to use ENV variables to make this static hardcoded values to become dynamic, so anyone on the fly can set these details using ENV vars. Can someone help me how I can achieve this. How to set them in such way from code so it can be dynamically passed as ENV vars in k8's deployment ?

My current deployment.yaml file as below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: go-demo-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: go-demo-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: go-demo-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: go-demo-app
          image: dockerhub/go-api:latest
          resources: {}
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8001
```

The above is working fine as the db server name is hardcoded in the code and now I can looking to pass it dynamically using ENV vars via code which I can refer in k8's deployment

Comment: do you have any .yaml deployment config?

Comment: Thanks @DavidYappeter, yes I have my deployment config which i have updated in question

Comment: you can use os.Getenv https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv. Or you can use something like viper https://github.com/spf13/viper.

Comment: you can add env on your deployment config, follow this guide
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/ . 

Put it inside `spec.template.spec.containers.env`
Don't forget to apply it after changing the config
and, use os.Getenv().

Comment: For this, I need to specify it in my golang code right? I am wondering how can I specify it in my code to get dynamic values passed via ENV in my deployment ?

Comment: the env that you assign in the config will initialize the env variables inside the container. With that, you can use os.Getenv() to get the env variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the .yaml to

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: go-demo-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: go-demo-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: go-demo-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: go-demo-app
          image: dockerhub/go-api:latest
          resources: {}
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8001
          env:
            - name: DB_USER
              value: username
            - name: DB_PASSWORD 
              value: password
            - name: DB_NAME     
              value: db_name
            - name: DB_HOST     
              value: db_server_name
            - name: DB_PORT     
              value: "3306"
```

`kubectl apply -f /path/to/file`

on your code, change the initialization into

```
var (
    DB_USER     = os.Getenv("DB_USER")
    DB_PASSWORD = os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
    DB_NAME     = os.Getenv("DB_NAME")
    DB_HOST     = os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    DB_PORT     = os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
)
```

I change const to var because it is not allowed

Comment: Thanks a lot @David, this helped me to learn something new today and solved my issue..Thanks again :)